# After changing URLs, how do I clear the old URLs out of Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, url

I've recently changed the url structure of my site for SEO purposes from...

`example.com/this_is_the_page`

...to...

`example.com/this-is-the-page`

The `sitemap.xml` is up to date and Google Search Console knows about it but it's still listing the old URLs. How is it best to clear out Google Search Console so that it only sees the new URLs?

The old URLs redirect to the new ones so no issues around access.

Comment: Where in GSC are you seeing the old URLs that is cluttering up reports for you?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm seeing them in 'Coverage > Valid > Submitted and Indexed'